# Git workflow for content editors

Tags: git

I have a specific workflow that I need some help with.

We have a remote staging server that hosts our CMS. Content editors make changes to things like the (blog etc...) there. They then submit a request to me to push the changes to the remote repository. The Git repo is on Bitbucket and then is setup for continuous deployment to our CDN (Netlify) using their built in webhooks.

At the client's request, I am trying to figure out a way for the (non technical) content editors to manage their own commits, but I also need to be cautious that they are not committing changes outside of their scope. Additionally, I have to make the assumption that the person making the commit knows nothing about command line.

Myself personally, I think this is a pipe dream on the clients part, but I am open for suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

The "fork and edit" button in GitHub does pretty much what you want.  This allows someone to click the "edit" icon, make changes in their browser, and then generate a pull request against the original repository.  None of this requires the command line.

Since they can't commit directly, repository owners have a chance to review changes before they are accepted, which deals with the "be cautious that they are not committing changes outside of their scope" issue.

I'm not entirely familiar with BitBucket, but taking a cursory look through their documentation it appears that [they support a similar feature](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/edit-online-351764818.html).